# How to change values in a JSON array in Ajax

Tags: javascript

I have a json array as below in a hidden input. I am trying to update charge value using ajax on a button click.

```
[{"2018-06-19":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},
 {"2018-06-20":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},
 {"2018-06-21":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},
 {"2018-06-22":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},
 {"2018-06-23":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},
 {"2018-06-24":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}}]
```

My hidden input and Button

```
<input type="hidden" name="chargeArray" id="chargeArray" value='[{"2018-06-19":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},{"2018-06-20":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},{"2018-06-21":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},{"2018-06-22":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},{"2018-06-23":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},{"2018-06-24":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}}]' />

<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="change_room_charge();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
```

I have tried it with this, but it is failing. charge value is not changing to new value.

```
function change_room_charge(){
    var chargeArray = JSON.parse($('#chargeArray').val());

     $.each(chargeArray, function (index, item) {
         item[0].charge = item[0].charge.replace(666);
     });

     $('#chargeArray').val(JSON.stringify(chargeArray));
}
```

What i want is to change all existing charge values in hidden input to new value.

Comment: Where is the Ajax? I don't see any

Comment: What is failing

Comment: @JordanS new value is not applying to charge value. What i want is to change all existing charge values to new value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: `foo = JSON.parse(bar); foo[0].charge = 666; bar = JSON.stringify(foo)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you are doing is very strange, but I'm going with it. You have your objects keyed by a date so you need to go get that key first. So in the code below, I get the key by finding all the keys for the item and taking the first one. From there you can set the value to whatever you want and then put it back into the input.

```js
function change_room_charge() {
  var chargeArray = JSON.parse($('#chargeArray').val());
  $.each(chargeArray, function(index, item) {
    var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
    item[key].charge = 666;
  });
  $('#chargeArray').val(JSON.stringify(chargeArray));
  console.log($('#chargeArray').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="chargeArray" id="chargeArray" value='[{"2018-06-19":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},{"2018-06-20":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},{"2018-06-21":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},{"2018-06-22":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},{"2018-06-23":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}},{"2018-06-24":{"charge":55000,"xcharge":15000}}]' />
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="change_room_charge();">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank You, This is what i am exactly looking for.